# VLC plays just one video: vdpau_display vout display error

Tags: drivers, 16.04, video, vlc

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad E525 with this GPU:

`00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sumo [Radeon HD 6480G]`

After upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04 (fglrx driver) I have the following issue with VLC: it plays one video per opening it. If I'd like to play a next video / open another one, it will not display anything, just plays the sound of the video. After restarting VLC it will play that video.

I see this error message in the log:

`vdpau_display vout display error: presentation queue display failure: An invalid handle value was provided. Either the handle does not exist at all, or refers to an object of an incorrect type.`

I've Googled around, but nothing really helped. I've also tried to [upgrade VLC a bit](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/install-latest-vlc-2-2-4-ubuntu-16-04-via-ppa/). Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Did someone met this issue? Could someone help?